# Add value to Choice field through ClientContext API

Tags: client-object-model, custom-list, choice-field

I'd like to add and select values to a choice field in a document library. Something obviously more tricky than I remembered.

I'm doing something like this but it doesn't work. The value gets added to the field in list views but not to the Choice column.

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://mymachine");
Web currentWeb = ctx.Web;
ctx.Load(currentWeb);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

SP.List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Doclib");
ctx.Load(list);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
ctx.Load(items);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();


foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
{
    ctx.Load(listItem.File);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    if (listItem.File.Name.Equals(fileName))
    {
        var processValue = "A Value";
        listItem["MetaProcess"] = processValue;
        //SP.FieldChoice itemType = ctx.CastTo<SP.FieldChoice>(list.Fields.GetByTitle("MetaProcess"));
        //itemType.Choices = new[] { "Agenda", "Agreement", "Full text", "Minutes", "News Item", "Reference" };
        //itemType.Update();
        //ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
    listItem.Update();
}
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did select to work in another route using the Camelot .NET Connector for SharePoint instead!

Answer (score -2):

the following works for me.

```
    calendarDropDown = (DropDownList)TemplateContainer.FindControl("calendarDropDown");
    if (ControlMode == SPControlMode.New || ControlMode == SPControlMode.Edit)
    {
        SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPListCollection lists = currentWeb.Lists;
        foreach (SPList list in lists)
        {
            if (list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.Events)
            {
                calendarDropDown.Items.Add(list.Title);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And this will run in ClientContext?

Comment: This is not a code with ClientContext, but with classic server side object model